# The Frobenius-Nakayama Formula

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, modules

I am currently reading a paper where it refers to *the usual Frobenius-Nakayama formula describing quotients of an induced module.* It is refering to the following result:

> If $k$ is a field, $P$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, $F$ is a $kP$-module and $W$ is a $kG$-module, then we have that
>   $\operatorname{Hom}_{kP}(F,W_{P})\cong_{k}\operatorname{Hom}_{kG}(\operatorname{Ind}_{P}^{G}(F),W).$

However, having searched for the Frobenius-Nakayama formula, I cannot find it in any reliable sources. Does anybody know of a good source for this result, and/or if the result is normally referred to by an alternative name?

Comment: Another name for this result (or rather, something that implies it) is "induction is left-adjoint to restriction."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over a field of characteristic not dividing the group order, this is called Frobenius reciprocity.  The version you give is usually called Frobenius-Nakayama reciprocity.

See [page 58-59](http://books.google.com/books?id=p7ylsZUmK3MC&lpg=PA58lr&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Alperin's Local Representation Theory for a proof.

A very introductory treatment is given on [page 231](http://books.google.com/books?id=PiJMr6kZP44C&lpg=PA231&&pg=PA231) of James–Liebeck's Representations and Characters of Groups.

A more general version is proved on [page 46](http://books.google.com/books?id=cezF63340GAC&lpg=PA46&pg=PA46) of Benson's Representations and Cohomology.

Comment: Thanks for a very quick and helpful response. The reference to Benson's book is extremely useful.

Comment: No prob.  I added two more treatments.  A should be better if you are doing group theory. J-L should be better if you're just learning character theory, and B might be better if you are doing representation theory.