# Induced Brauer character

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let H is a  subgroup of G. How we can show that $(1_{H^0})^G$ is reducible Brauer character of G. Where $1_{H^0}$ is principal Brauer character of H.

Comment: I'm a bit thrown off by your notation. Are you talking about inducing the trivial character from $H$ to $G$?  If so Frobenius reciprocity tells us this induction contains a copy of the trivial representation of $G$ (as either a submodule or a quotient), but then provided $H \ne G$ this can't be everything for dimension reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately Frobenius reciprocity does not necessarily hold in modular case.

Comment: In this case Nate's comment still works. The trivial representation is liftable to the ring of algebraic integers, Frobenius reciprocity holds in the field of algebraic numbers, the decomposition restricts to a local ring at the relevant prime, and then can be reduced mod that prime to give a decomposition of Brauer characters (though what was irreducible in char 0 may be reducible in char p)

Comment: Here is one version that holds without any lifting (but one has to be careful where the simple modules are located in the composition series): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156984/the-frobenius-nakayama-formula

Comment: Although Frobenius reciprocity does not hold over fields of positive characteristic, the more general Nakayama relations do, which are the same thing, but with Hom implace of inner product. More generally, $(1_H)^G$ is just a permutation module and obviously has a fixed point.

Comment: Thank you all for your good responses.

Answer (score 2):

As Nate mentioned, this can be seen from Frobenius reciprocity since this module can be lifted to the integers. However, we can also directly find a nonzero, proper submodule.

Suppose $G$ is a finite group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with index $n$, and $p$ is a prime. Let $\rho:G \to \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be given by sending a group element $g$ to the permutation matrix corresponding to the permutation induced by $G$ on the cosets of $H$. We can choose a basis of $V=(\mathbb{F}_p)^n$ starting with an arbitrary $\vec{e}_H$ and defining $\vec{e}_{Hg} = \vec{e}_{H} \cdot g$. We have $\vec{e}_{H} \cdot h = \vec{e}_H$ for all $h \in H$ and $\vec{e}_{Hg} \cdot k = \vec{e}_{H} \cdot g \cdot k = \vec{e}_{Hgk}$.

This representation has character $(1_H)^G$.

This representation is reducible if $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ (otherwise $n=1$ and we get the irreducible trivial representation). We show this by giving an explicit nonzero proper submodule:

Let $W = \left\{ \alpha \cdot \left( \sum_{g \in T} \vec{e}_{Hg} \right) : \alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p \right\}$ where $T$ is a transversal of $H$ in $G$.

This is a one-dimensional trivial submodule of $V$. If $n > 1$, then it is a proper submodule and $V$ is reducible.

Answer (score 2):

There is a version of Frobenius reciprocity that holds over any field:

If $G$ is a finite group, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $Ind_H^G$ and $Res_H^G$ are adjoint functors between $Rep_k(H)$ and $Rep_k(G)$ for any field $k$.

If you don't like this functor language, this concretely means that $$Hom_G(Ind_H^G(V), W) \cong Hom_H(V, Res_H^G(W))$$
and
$$Hom_H(Res_H^G(W), V) \cong Hom_G(W, Ind_H^G(V))$$

For all representations $V$ and $W$ over $k$ of $H$ and $G$ respectively.

Applying these when both $V$ and $W$ are the trivial representation shows that $Ind_H^G(1)$ has a trivial submodule as well as a trivial quotient.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your question should follow from the following standard result from Mackey theory:

Let $H$ be a finite index subgroup of a finite group $G$, and let $(\sigma, W)$ be a (finite dimensional, complex) representation of $H$, and consider the induced representation $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G \sigma$ of $G$.  This is the vector space of all functions $\varphi: G \rightarrow W$ such that $\varphi(hg) = \sigma(w) \varphi(g)$ for all $h \in H$ and $g \in G$, on which $G$ acts by right translation: $g \cdot \varphi(x) = \varphi(xg)$.

Let $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(W,W)$ be the set of linear transformations from $W$ to itself, and consider the set $\mathcal I$ of *functions* $$A: G \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(W,W)$$

satisfying the condition

$$ A(h_1gh_2) = \sigma(h_1) \circ A(g) \circ \sigma(h_2)$$

for all $h_1, h_2 \in H, g \in G$.  For each $A \in \mathcal I$, define $\Phi \in \operatorname{Hom}_G(\operatorname{Ind}_H^G \sigma, \operatorname{Ind}_H^G \sigma)$ by

$$\Phi(\varphi)(g) = \sum\limits_{x \in H \backslash G} A(gx^{-1}) \varphi(x).$$

Then $A \mapsto \Phi$ defines a bijection from $\mathcal I$ onto the set $\operatorname{Hom}_G(\operatorname{Ind}_H^G \sigma, \operatorname{Ind}_H^G \sigma)$ of intertwining operators from $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G \sigma$ to itself.

Let $V = \operatorname{Ind}_H^G 1_H$, where $1_H$ is the trivial representation of $H$ over the complex numbers.  I assume by your question, you're asking equivalently why $V$ is never an irreducible representation of $G$.

To say that $V$ is irreducible is the same as saying that the only intertwining operators from $V$ to itself are scalar multiplication maps.  Thus, you just need to show that there are nontrivial intertwining operators from $V$ to itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. But in ny case representations are not complex . They are modular representation.

Comment: In complex characters we can show it. I am trying to prove it for Brauer characters